# Rocket chat enable ssl in apache

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, openssl, letsencrypt, chat

I have installed rocket chat on docker - on Debian 9 OS.
I am unable to enable https for the same.
I can access it using fqdn - http://chat.xyz.com:3003

I have generated ssl certificates using certbot.
I am using below configuration in apache:
`https://docs.rocket.chat/installation/manual-installation/configuring-ssl-reverse-proxy`

````
    ServerAdmin it@xyz.com
    ServerName chat.xyz.com

    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog /var/log/chat.xyz.com_error.log
    TransferLog /var/log/chat.xyz.com_access.log

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/cloud-no.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/cloud-no.com.key

    <Location />
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3003/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:3003/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPassReverse /          http://localhost:3003/
</VirtualHost>```

I have also enabled necessary modules in apache - proxy_http, proxy_wstunnel, etc
I have referred and tried many sites/guides before posting here. 
Please help me.
````

Comment: Please describe what actually happens when you try to access the service over HTTPS. Do you get a certificate error from the browser? Or does the connection fail altogether? Or does the web server send you an error page instead of expected results? What does it say?

Comment: Hi, the hostname of the server is cloud-no.com --  by default roundcube is pointed to this.
Https is enabled for https://cloud-no.com and even when i try to access https://chat.xyz.com - it redirects to the roundcube webmail -- instead of rocketchat.

Please note that we also have other applications like nextcloud - with url - demoxyz-no.com -- can access the same with https.